# User input in batch file

Tags: variables, batch-file, user-input

I have a batch file that looks like this, which takes a picture of a webpage and crops it:

```
cd C:\users\***\Downloads\IECapt-2008-06-10
IECapt --delay=10000 --url=http://test.com/picture.swf?id=1 --out="C:\users\***\My Documents\picture.png"
cd C:\users\***\My Documents
convert picture.png -trim picture.png

ftp -s:place_img.txt
```

I was wondering is there was a way that I could alter this script to accept user input to replace the URL and the file name with what the user inputted. For example, the user would input a URL and a file name and it would replace these things:

```
cd C:\users\***\Downloads\IECapt-2008-06-10
IECapt --delay=10000 --url=(((http://test.com/picture.swf?id=1))) --out="C:\users\***\My Documents\((picture)).png"
cd C:\users\***\My Documents
convert ((picture)).png -trim ((picture)).png

ftp -s:place_img.txt
```

(((URL being replaced)))

((File name being replaced))

**This is the "place_picture.txt" file:**

```
open test.com
username
pass
hash
bin
lcd c:\users\***\My Documents
cd public_html/test.com/test
put picture.png
bye
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ask questions in a batch, and the answers get stored in 'environment variables' which can be used in further commands.

```
set /p picno=Picture number?
IECapt --delay=10000 --url=http://test.com/picture.swf?id=%picno% --out="C:\users\***\My Documents\pic%picno%.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access parameters in a batch file using `%1 %2 etc`.
For example, if you had `myBatch.bat` and ran `myBatch Hello World`, %1 would be "Hello" and %2 would be "World".

As for updating your FTP script, I am not sure. The only thing I can think of off the top of my head would be to `MPUT` all png files in the directory and then move/delete the files after processing so they aren't picked up again.